# what does the global agent of the jenkine pipeline do?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I read this [doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent-parameters).

> none
>
> When applied at the top-level of the pipeline block no global agent will be allocated for the entire Pipeline run and each stage section will need to contain its own agent section. For example: agent none

What is the limitation if there is no global agent? Any docs?